# Cannot shrink virtualbox HD using vboxmanage even though it is of dynamic size

Tags: virtualbox

```
 > vboxmanage showhdinfo mydisk.vdi
 UUID:                 ff4e397d-f2c8-4c19-ac03-1d4ee31d9004
 Accessible:           yes
 Logical size:         569189 MBytes
 Current size on disk: 198771 MBytes
 Type:                 normal (base)
 Storage format:       VDI
 Format variant:       dynamic default
 ...
 .. 
 .

 > vboxmanage modifyhd mydisk.vdi --resize 100000
 0%...
 Progress state: VBOX_E_NOT_SUPPORTED
 VBoxManage: error: Resize hard disk operation for this format is not implemented yet!

> vboxmanage --version
4.1.12_Ubuntur77245
```

What am I doing wrong? I have found hundreds of threads saying that it has to be dynamic drive in order for it to work, but this drive is dynamic!

EDIT: 
    It was my mistake. resize does not shrink the virtual HD, only grows it. The error message from vboxmanage is cryptic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

100000 is less than 569189. Resize doesn't support shrinking disks. Is this typo just here or in your system also?

Comment: Nope, I am trying to shrink it, did not know that. my bad. I will look up the ways to read from VDI without starting VM I guess and copy it over to another smaller one.